# Are there examples of SPROC mappings and usage with Fluent NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, stored-procedures, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I'm looking for an example of how I would/should use the SqlUpdate, SqlDelete, and SqlInsert parts of Fluent NHibernate in my mappings.

I have a standard

```
public class MyObjectMap : ClassMap<MyObject> {

    public MyObjectMap() {
        Table("MyObjectsTable");

        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Map(x => x.This, "That");
        // Ad nauseam

        // how do I use this part?
        SqlUpdate(" some sql here ");
```

The question is, how do I make use of a StoredProcedurePart in this way?  How do I specify only the right parameters?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this - I am investigating FNH for a new project and this feature could be useful - thanks!

Comment: Not with this.  I did implement a "SQLCommand" class that hooks into the NH session (primarily for logging purposes), uses dynamics for mapping to real-world objects.  Once I fully described it, the response I got was "Oh, so, you wrote Massive in NH?"